# Keydown function is not working on aspx page.!

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Am trying to add input on one `textbox` to other `textbox` on same time using jquery **keydown** . For some reason its not working, Am new to coding so helps and criticism will be appreciated..!

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Text Box1"></asp:Label><br/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br/><br/>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Text Box2"></asp:Label><br/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>

<script>

    $('#TextBox1').keydown(function () {
        $('#TextBox2').val($(this).val())
    })

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to use [`Control.ClientID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx) i.e. `$('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').keydown(`

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#TextBox1').keydown(function () {
            $('#TextBox2').val($(this).val())
        })
    });

Comment: i tried both,its still not working .!

Comment: put your code in  *$(document).ready.*

Comment: or recall function Sys.Application.add_load(functionName);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Control.ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the control ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET

```
$('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').keydown(function () {
    $('#<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>').val($(this).val())
})
```